# How to exit a script in Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

I am using [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/)'s Spyder. When I am creating a new script with the command `exit()`, and run it there, this command kills the kernel:

> It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.

What's the right way to stop a script in this runtime environment?

Comment: The corresponding Spyder issue is now https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1974 .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: In at least Spyder 5.0.3, the call to `sys.exit()` does not kill the kernel any more! *(Thanks to @bhushan for the info!)*

For earlier versions, the following still holds:

To exit the script, one can

- raise a silent exception with `raise SystemExit(0)` (without traceback)
- or a custom exception like `raise Exception('my personal exit message')`
- or encapsulate the code into a function (e.g. `main`) and use `return` inside.

If one wants to keep the call to `exit()` in the script, one can

- Switch to "Execute in a new dedicated Python interpreter" or
- register an exit handler at the IPython console:

  ```
    def exit_handler(): raise Exception("exit()"), get_ipython().ask_exit = exit_handler
  ```

Comment: Is this answer of question?

Comment: @Lafada: I do not know yet. See https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1974.

Comment: If this is not answer please put it in comments or update existing question only. If you post as answer then others will get wrong impression.

Answer (score 4):

As Robert Pollak suggest, the comment in [Spyderlib Issue 1974 #4](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1974#c4) is a better solution. Just define a function which cause an exception, and call this function if you want to stop the execute of script inside spyder.

```
def f(): raise Exception("Found exit()")
```

Comment: Thank you, @ollydbg23! I have included your answer into mine.

Comment: How does one execute a function defined in a running program from outside of the program?

Answer (score 1):

Built-in solution can be used:

```
import sys

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

To interrupt the execution of Spyder without warning, you can call

```
raise SystemExit(0)
```

Answer (score -2):

Solution that works for me:
On windows with Spyder 5 installed. I run Spyder from an Anaconda PowerShell Prompt, so when Spyder stalls, I can go to the shell and use `Ctrl+c` to kill any process.

Comment: The question is not about when Spyder stalls, so this answer is off-topic.