# Properly terminate script without error message in Spyder

Tags: python, exit, spyder

SO for my project in python, I am taking two inputs say a & b as integer values. Now the code goes like:

```
import sys
a = input("enter a")
b = input("enter b")
if a < b:
    print(" enter a greater than b and try again")
    sys.exit()

# Rest of the code is here
```

Now this works fine. But creates an extra statement

```
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
```

And I do not want that as the user may think that the code's functioning is not proper. So is there any way that this statement is not shown or any other function which would exit the code without printing anything except the line which I have written?

**NOTE** I have tried exit() but it continues to execute the code beneath it. Also, I have noticed [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19747371/1025391) but the approaches listed there don't work in this case.

**EDIT**: I am adding some more information. I need to put this exit function into a user-defined function so that every time the user enters some wrong data, the code will call this user-defined function and will exit the code.
If I try to put my code in an if else statement like

```
def end():
    print("incorrect input try again")
    os.exit()

a = input("enter data")
if a < 10:
    end()
b = input ("enter data")
if b < 20:
   end()
# more code here
```

I don't know why but I can't even define this user-defined function in the end as it raises the error of undefined function end(). I'm using Python with [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/) on Windows.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had solved this problem but unfortunately I hadn't. So please help!!

Comment: @moooeeeep currently I am using Spyder for coding on windows and I don' t have any such thing in my code.

Comment: Then this seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25928377/1025391 (Though maybe a bit outdated as the behavior is slightly different apparantly) You'd better state such information directly in your question.

Comment: (I hope you are using Python 3?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os._exit()`

```
a = int(input("enter a"))
b = int(input("enter b"))
if a < b:
    print(" enter a greater than b and try again")
    os._exit(0)
```

Comment: there is no attribute exit() in os.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine without any warnings even!! :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work just fine:

```
import sys

def end():
    print("incorrect input try again")
    sys.exit(1)

a = input("enter data")
if int(a) < 10:
    end()
b = input ("enter data")
if int(b) < 20:
    end()
```

I used the `sys.exit` and fixed your conditions to avoid comparing string with integers. I cannot see any additional messages in the output. Only this:

```
>py -3 test2.py
enter data1
incorrect input try again
>
```

Please also take notice of this qoute from python docs:

> The standard way to exit is sys.exit(n). [os]_exit() should normally only
>   be used in the child process after a fork().

It also works in the [repl](https://repl.it/J1cU/0)

Comment: If the code is run for the first time, it shows `C:\Users\abc\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2889: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit` and if on the same console if I execute the code again, it does not show the warning but shows this: `An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit`. I don't want to display these messages.

Comment: The code exits properly but gives extra statements which I do not need to be printed.