# why does sys.exit crashes program/kernel?

Tags: python, crash, kernel, spyder

Using Spyder 5.1.5 and coded a minesweeper game with help of freecodecamp.org for educational purpose. I'm pretty new to coding and don't get all nuances. The kernel crashes after clicking "Ok" in the "Game Over" window when clicked on a mine before. Code snippet below.

```
def show_mine(self):
self.cell_btn_object.configure(bg='red')
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, 'You clicked on a mine!','Game Over!', 0)
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Well, [sys exit](https://www.notion.so/pollenteam/Python-Tips-a600d4414c384e1ba41c94ed3b9a32c3#922847f864164f69903f6423558e0668) is supposed to raise an exception

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour is expected, sys.exit() terminates the program using an exception. If you want to continue running the program, i suggest removing sys.exit(). I cannot gurantee that this works because you didnt supply enough code. In this case, the best thing would be to show us all the code you have, so we can male sure that there are no variables containing the wrong state for example.

Comment: The kernel crashes and Windows says that the program is not responding, have to kill it afterwards. How to just close the window of the game after clicking "Ok" in the "game over" screen?

Comment: Well that shouldnt happen, take a look at these workarounds though https://stackoverflow.com/a/25928378/13526701